# Can we change Case of input data in SQL LOADER ctl file?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am trying to insert data from csv to a table using sql loader.
My csv has data in small Caps .But I want the data in the table to be in Large cap for some columns For some Columns it should be InitCap.

````
        INFILE 'abc.csv'
        INSERT INTO TABLE T_DETAILS
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
        (   
    INITCAP(f_name), 
    UPPER(f_code)```

But i am getting error like

> **SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 16. Expecting "," or ")", found "(".
>     INITCAP(f_name),**
>            ^
````

Answer (score 3):

You can, but not like that. Should've been

```
load data
infile 'abc.csv' 
insert
into table t_details
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols
(f_name     "initcap(:f_name)",
 f_code     "upper(:f_code)"
)
```